# My palindrome program is giving an exception?

Tags: c++, c

I'm trying to run below my program which is for `Palindrome` but it's giving me an `Exception error`, please help? I'm using `Visual studio 2013`.

```
#include<iostream>

int main(){
    char a[100], b[100];

    std::cout << "This is a program to check palindrome or not." << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Enter your string:\n" << std::endl;
    gets(a);

    /*Here string does copy..*/
    strcpy(a, b);

    /*Here string does reverse..*/
    strrev(b);

    /*Here string does compare*/
    if (strcmp(a, b) == 0){
        std::cout << "Congrats, It's palindrome!" << std::endl;
    }
    else{
        std::cout << "Sorry BOSS but this is not a palindrome." << std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

```
char *strcpy(char *dest, const char *src);
```

The destination is the first argument, the source second. Change your copy command to

```
strcpy(b, a);
```

Comment: @nitingoyal: Well, that isn't a palindrome, so it is correct.

Comment: I'll accept your answer after `8 minutes` :) ..thanks once again